# Css hover zoom effect wont work

Tags: javascript, css

I have one problem about CSS hover zoom effect.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/ZWYjmr)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see there is red color div. When you click the div `.CRtW11` will opening. So i want to add hover zoom effect for `.ReaC` div. I tried the following transform effect but it doesn't worked.

```
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
```

I don't understand where i am doing wrong anyone can help me in this regard ?

**HTML**

**CSS**

```
.cR {
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   position:relative;
   background-color:red;
   cursor:pointer;
}
.CRtW11 {
   position:absolute;
   width:215px;
   height:40px;
   background-color:blue;
   opacity:0;
   transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom 0px; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(0); 
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
   z-index:1;
   margin-top:-45px;
   border-radius:30px;
   -webkit-border-radius:30px;
   -moz-border-radius:30px;
   padding:5px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.CRtW11-active {
   box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease; 
   -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
}

.ReaC {
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   border-radius:50%;
   -webkit-border-radius:50%;
   -moz-border-radius:50%;
   background-color:red;
   margin-right:5px;
   display:none;
   opacity:0;
  -moz-transition: ease 0.2s;
  -o-transition: ease 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.2s;
  transition: ease 0.2s;
}
.ReaC:hover
{
   background:yellow;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the following from `.ReaC-active`

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
```

Comment: And also add a high-value z-index to the hover event code to bring the item forward. Something like `z-index: 100;`